# Exchange Object/Class data between Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, linux, data-transfer, data-transfer-objects

I need to pass data between c++ program and a Java GUI that is showing that data. I can put that data in a class but the c++ program could be running on linux(raspberry pie) and java may or may not be on windows. What options do i have? 
Kindly help me for same machine processes and also if they are on different machines.
P.S.
On different machines internet connection is available.

Comment: Take a look at Apache Thrift - http://thrift.apache.org/

Answer (score 3):

You may want to implement some [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

I suggest using a simple textual serialization format like [JSON](http://json.org/) (but you might consider also YAML or even XML). There are many JSON libraries available, like [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) (in C), [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) (in C++) and several for Java.

Of course, you need some form of [Inter-Process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). This can be sockets or pipes. Read e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) or some other tutorial. Maybe have some [Event Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (e.g. [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/)) or even use [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) (or perhaps some HTTP server library)

<sup>You could use binary serialization like [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or using [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/) but it is usually not worth the trouble.</sup>

Comment: +1 There are many forms for serialization.  Any which works across platform will do but text serialization formats are usually easier to understand/read/fix.